# Java: compareTo not sorting correctly

Tags: java, sorting

I have this `compareTo` code for my list:

```
public int compareTo(className a) 
{               
    return (this.long1 > a.long1) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

When I use `Collections.sort(list)`, I get the following error: `Comparison method violates its general contract!`

When I change it to `if (this.long1 >= a.long2)`, it works, but it does not sort properly. The longs are sorted in order, then out of order, then in order. Using `>=`, the output looks like this:

```
...
2000100
2000101
2000102
1000100
1000101
2000101
2000102
...
```

Now, duplicates *do* happen, and they need to be sorted correctly. It doesn't matter if the duplicates appear first or last, as long as they're properly grouped in order, like so:

```
...
2000100
2000101
2000101
2000102
2000102
1000100
1000101
...
```

How would I do this properly? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The list is still being sorted out of order with all of the below suggestions. Is this because it's a `List<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>();`? I can't use what I'm used to from C#: `List<Class> list = new List<Class>()`.

Comment: You do not handle equality, in that case, you need to return `0`.

Comment: Google your error, there're many posts that solve your problem.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, not really. None of these suggestions are working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should return 0 when the two numbers are equal, or just use `Long.compare` :

```
public int compareTo(className a) 
{               
    return Long.compare(this.long1,a.long1);
}
```

Comment: I like this one. `Long.compare()`.

Comment: I'd like to state that none of these suggestions are working, including all the information in the `duplicate` post, but since the post was marked as duplicate, there isn't much I can do. Still getting the same defect: list is sorted out of order.

Comment: @EduardoScissaro You can still edit your question. Add relevant code, inputs and outputs.

Comment: Output is the same. Code is the same. I'm going to keep at it for a while.

Comment: @EduardoScissaro You can show how you initialize your list, you can show the code of your class that implements `compareTo`. Perhaps there's something there that would help solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed. I thought it was an issue with `compareTo`, but it's much deeper than that. I'm going to try and solve it myself, though.

Comment: Found the problem, which was totally my fault, somewhere else deep in the code, and it was messing with `compareTo`. While this doesn't answer the problem I was having, it is indeed correct when removing the code that shouldn't even be interacting with this in the first place. Technically, this answer is still correct... therefore, +1 and check.

Answer (score 4):

```
return (this.long1 > a.long1) ? 1 : -1;
```

If both numbers are equal, this returns -1, not 0.

```
return (this.long1 >= a.long1) ? 1 : -1;
```

Now 1 is equal, still not 0.
Correct:

```
if(this.long1 > a.long1) return 1;
if(this.long1 < a.long1) return -1;
return 0;
```

Comment: Although this is not incorrect but i would use something stackoverflow.com/a/33367246/1085186 as it uses library code and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

A correct solution would do this:

```
public int compareTo(className a) {               
    return this.long1 > a.long1 ? 1 : this.long1 < a.long1 ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: I just added the same solution, but in a different order. :p

Comment: Although this is not incorrect but i would use something http://stackoverflow.com/a/33367246/1085186 as it uses library code and more readable.